# In MongoDB, how to roll back update to one collection if update fails on another collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

For example, a user is deleted in the `members` collection. Thus, all of its documents must also be deleted in all other collections.

After successfully deleting the user from the `members` collection, how do I ensure that the cascading deletes will succeed in other collections? What if they don't succeed? How do I know of this inconsistency that is now in my database?

Comment: By using [Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions/)

Comment: That documents its usage with `insert`. How about `update`?

Comment: No, it is not. Did you read the page? It's just the example which use an insert.